# How to get values from Series using column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I get the list of column names as follows:

```
featuresA = [str(col) + '_x' for col in group.index]
```

where group is Series. I receive a list of 10 column names like 'Col1_x', 'Col2_x', etc.

Now I want to read Series values into a DataFrame object:

```
mergedrow = pd.DataFrame()
mergedrow[featuresA] = group[featuresA]
```

The error message says:

```
raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
```

When I directly convert `group` to DataFrame using group.to_frame(), the result is 0.

The complete code looks as follows:

```
featuresA = [str(col) + '_x' for col in group.index]
featuresB = [str(col) + '_y' for col in match.iloc[[idx]].columns]
mergedrow = pd.DataFrame()
mergedrow[featuresA] = group[featuresA]
mergedrow[featuresB] = match.iloc[[idx]]
```

UPDATE:
This is the whole error message:

```
    raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['airportResources.baggage_x' 'airportResources.arrivalTerminal_x'\n 'arrivalAirportFsCode_x' 'operationalTimes.scheduledGateArrival.dateLocal_x'\n 'schedule.flightType_x' 'schedule.serviceClasses_x' 'status_x'\n 'operationalTimes.actualDateTime_x'] not in index"
```

Comment: Could you post 2 line of group? `mergedrow[featuresA] = group[featuresA]` actually your dataframe is not created yet so, when you you use `mergedrow[featuresA]` key error is raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Series.values` gives the values for you to create dataframe.

If you are trying to convert series to one row dataframe you could do like this,

```
import pandas as pd

In [33]: group
Out[33]: 
a    0.316286
b   -0.338733
c   -1.050260
d   -0.365461
e    0.996902
dtype: float64

In [34]: group.index
Out[34]: Index([u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd', u'e'], dtype='object')

In [35]: group.values
Out[35]: array([ 0.31628576, -0.33873327, -1.05026027, -0.3654615 ,  0.99690196])

In [38]: featuresA = [str(col) + '_x' for col in group.index]

In [39]: df = pd.DataFrame([group.values], columns = featuresA)

In [40]: df
Out[40]: 
    a_x       b_x      c_x       d_x       e_x
0  0.316286 -0.338733 -1.05026 -0.365461  0.996902
```